# How to keep side of cube same as vertical angle increases?

Tags: drawing, perspective

I'm learning perspective and I'm drawing a cube of same size lower and lower on the vertical axis as so:

[image]

How do I draw the side correctly?

What poses a challenge to me is that the `top-left line` (green line in photo) of the cube needs to get longer and longer as I get a higher and higher perspective. But that `line` (green line in photo) forms also the side of the box which means that I needs to show more of it. However, the left-right perspective has not changed and therefore I think the side of the box needs to remain the same.

There's a contradiction here: as I bring the box down, I'm forced to exposed more of the side of the box - and not only more of the roof - because the side of the box is related to the roof by the green line.

How do I overcome this?

i.e.

If I keep the side constant and increase the roof size only... it looks even worse:

[image]

So I don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the sides of the box would remain the same unless you move the box left or right based on your perspective. The length of your green line will slightly increase based on the angle of the line.

How to overcome this?

I think it would help to draw using a perspective grid.

[image: drawing cubes]